# Powershell, run a cmd command with latin character like ä, ö, ü

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I've a problem with latin character in powershell. I've tried to run a cmd command in a powershell script, because we work with Sumatra-PDF (printing tool).

The command looks like that:

```
$Befehlkpl = "W:\SumatraPDF\sumatrapdf.exe `-print-to $Drucker2 `-print`-settings `"paper=" + $Papier1 + ", " + $Farbeinstellung + ", " + $Seiteneinstellung + "`" "

$Befehlkpl | cmd -encoding 'utf8'
```

Now one of these variable can include a ä or ü or ö. The console-output is allright, but the respond of cmd is not working
The encoding command was in every attempt not working.

Thank you very much for every advice!

Comment: If the *cmd* you have in your code is the `CMD.exe` it will not work this way because `CMD.exe` is an external executable and does not have a parameter `-encoding` and may not able to propery digest objects by pipeline. Why do you actually try to use another command line interface from the command line interface you're already using - PowerShell? ;-)

Comment: Take a look at Start-Process instead of cmd. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)

Comment: Wish I had the setup to really experiment with this, I'll be at a better computer later today and may try it then.  I have so many questions: Do environment variables assigned in PowerShell via $Env:EVarName survive the transition to CMD.EXE?  If so, then once CMD is executing, will %EVarName% correctly pass as a parameter to sumatrapdf?  Why can't you just call sumatrapdf and pass it the parameters?  Could you build a batch with SET= commands saving the strings with special characters, then pass them to sumatrapdf, and somehow call the dynamically crated batch file? So many questions!

Comment: @Darin Wow, what a waste of time and energy. ;-) ;-)   I'd prefer instead of tinkering with the old and mostly obsolete CMD doing it properly with pure PowerShell. ;-) :-*

Comment: @Olaf, one could argue that sports are waste of time and energy.  Similarly, I have a friend who has recently set himself on the path of building droids that use the RFID chips to control behavior the same as Disney is with their Star Wars droids. No real purpose or goal, he just wants to do it. As for PowerShell, I've been nose diving into it since November of last year so I wouldn't have to do CMD again.  But now that I don't have to do CMD, I find sometimes I want to.

Comment: @Darin That wasn't meant to stop you doing whatever you have fun with. ;-) If you like to spend your time doing this research that's fine. What I meant was that there is an easier  and probalby more robust way of doing what was asked using the right tool for the job. ;-)  .. have a nice Weekend!

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me HOWEVER as written it raises a syntax error about my use of escaped quotes, but completes the job exactly as expected

```
[string] $Drucker2 = "Text Only"
[string] $Option1 = "A4"
[string] $Option2 = "whatever"
[string] $Filenames = "Hello äüö World.pdf"
`"
Start-Process -FilePath "$env:comspec" -ArgumentList "/k","`"`"c:\program files\sumatrapdf\sumatrapdf.exe`"",-print-to,`"$Drucker2`",-print-settings,`"paper=$Option1","$Option2`",`"$Filenames`","`&",pause`" -Wait -WindowStyle Minimized
```

Note this is a conceptual answer to prove it works, you will need to change variables as required. once you prove it functions you can remove the & pause since that with /k was to debug the syntax errors, but do keep the -wait to ensure you can trap any runtime erroring.

I strongly suggest that you find a Cmd method as the contortions required getting it to work in alien PowerShell took me ages and I know that command line inside out.

DO NOT use -silent and remember PDF printing need the graphics rendering system so should not be hidden from cmd.exe which it expects to be running within as a graphics console. (e.g. do not run SumatraPDF on a headless server, without expecting problems)

By far the simplest method for drag and drop or other batch printing is to use the simplest of command lines and if you keep your printer names to the normal Latin range the only problem is long names which can be avoided by using short name equivalent thus the example above runs perfectly well using:-

```
set "$filename=%~s1"
"C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\sumatrapdf.exe" -print-to "Microsoft Print to PDF" -print-settings "paper=A4,Landscape" %$filename%
```

[image]
[image]